# Action de formulário conforme seleção de radio button não funciona

Tags: jquery

Estou fazendo uma validação de 2 radios buttons, onde dependendo de qual for selecionado o formulário encaminha para uma página diferente. Estou usando Jquery, conforme abaixo:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var form = $('form[name="cadastro"]'),
        radio = $('input[name="MERCADO"]'),
        choice = '';

    radio.change(function(e) {
        choice = this.value;
        if (choice === "ME") {
           form.attr('action', 'Checklist-P1-ME.php');
        } else {
           form.attr('action', 'Checklist-P1.php');
        }
    });
});
```

Os radios são esses:

```
    <input type="radio" name="MERCADO" value="MI" CHECKED/>MERCADO INTERNO<br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="MERCADO" value="ME" />MERCADO EXTERNO<br><br><br>
```

Mas o que acontece é que o Jquery só reconhece o valor MI se eu clicar no ME e depois clicar de volta no MI. É como se ele não reconhecesse o `checked` predefinido.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Porque não pões action do formulário default? consoante o input que começa checked?   Neste caso a action do formulário começaria como `Checklist-P1.php` por default

Comment: Não acredito que fiz uma pergunta com uma solução tão simples....deixei default a action e funcionou....obrigado

Comment: :P não há problema nenhum nisso, às vezes a solução obvia/simples passa-nos ao lado